# Is there any tool for Java's Spring MVC like ASP.NET MVC's Glimpse?

Tags: java, asp.net, spring-mvc, glimpse

Comming from .NET world, I would like to know if there is something like http://getglimpse.com/ to use in a Java Spring MVC project.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Glimpse is technically not .NET dependent. If you'd like to work on a port to Spring, let the Glimpse team know. We'd be happy to support you.

Comment: Thanks, @nikmd23! I'll consider this possibility. For now I'm just starting with java development but I liked your idea.

Comment: why dont you try Spring IDE or  Plugin for Spring on eclipse also have a  look into lucene which people say java equivalent of glimpse

Comment: Hi, @sandy! I can't see how Lucene can be compared to Glimpse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Insight allows you to look at the performance and internals of Spring web apps: http://www.springsource.org/insight

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JavaMelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/). This is good profiling framework for Java EE applications. 
You can annotate Spring beans and collect statistics about execution time, perfomance and erros.
Also JM provides posiblities for monitoring HTTP requests/respnses and DB loading.